# Reducing the distance in textbf environment

Tags: formatting, environments

I want to introduce a notation for concatenating vectors in a manuscript that I represent vectors with bold characters, `$\textbf{x}$`. The problem is defining it like `$\textbf{x}:\textbf{y}$` introduces an extra distance between two characters which is far more than `$\textbf{x:y}$`. On the other hand the latter is not what I am looking for since I need non-bold subscripts for vectors and I need to use two `$\textbf$` environments. Any suggestions?

```
\articleclass{document}
\begin{document}
This is bad concatenation $\textbf{x}:\textbf{y}$
This is good concatenation $\textbf{x:y}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Enclose the `:` itself in braces (to prevent it from being treated as a binary operator, which causes the space).

Comment: `:` is a considered a relation symbol; `$\mathbf{x}{:}\mathbf{y}$` is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

 %uncomment to make `:` act like `{:}` by default.
 %\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathord}{operators}{"3A} 

\begin{document}

$\mathbf{x}:\mathbf{y}$ 


$\mathbf{x}{:}\mathbf{y}$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sure `\mathbf` should be used; or the symbols could turn out to be in bold italic, if the formula is inside a theorem statement.

Comment: @Naji If you only need `:` in that context and never as a relation symbol, I'm sure David will be glad to add a way for inputting `:` directly.

Comment: I am actually quite satisfied with the responses. Although now what seems puzzling to me is that using $\bm$ keeps the characters in their variable format but usually vectors are represented with normal text format. The question is what to do to handle the case where in a theorem environment we would get normal format.

Comment: @egreg done: -)

Comment: @Naji `\bm` will use bold math italic no matter what the context is; if you choose to represent vectors by upright boldface, this should be the format also in theorem statements, that is, it should be independent on the context.

Comment: @Naji The whole point of `bm` is to give the bold version of a character so if it was in math italic it gives bold math italic. If you want upright bold then `\mathbf` will give that